# scrollbar is not initially visible in highstock

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am using highstock to create charts in my asp.net MVC application 
I have added a navigation along with it i have added a scroll bar 
I am viewing 4 charts in a single view, for all charts the horizontal scroll bar is visible only for one as show in the image

[image]

In the image the above chart's scrollbar is visible but not for the chart bellow it

But when i move my navigation bar a bit it displays the scrollbar like this

Bellow is my Razor for chart

```
var chart3 = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container3',
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            panning: true,
            panKey: 'shift',
            resetZoomButton: {
                position: {
                    //align: 'right', // by default
                    //verticalAlign: 'top', // by default
                    x: -10,
                    y: 350,
                    //height: 25
                },
                relativeTo: 'chart'
            }
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
            showFull: false
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                fill: 'none',
                stroke: 'none',
                'stroke-width': 0,
                r: 8,
                style: {
                    color: '#039',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                    },
                    select: {
                        fill: '#039',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                    // disabled: { ... }
                }
            },
            inputBoxWidth: 160,
            inputStyle: {
                color: '#039',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                color: 'black',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            buttons: [{
                type: 'minute',
                count: 60 * 6,
                text: '6h'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1d'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 7,
                text: '7d'
            },
            {
                type: 'day',
                count: 14,
                text: '2w'
            },
            {
                type: 'day',
                count: 21,
                text: '3w'

            },
            {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            },
            {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }]
        },
        navigator: {

            enabled: true,
            height: 30,
        },
        //scrollbar: {
        //    enabled: true,
        //    barBackgroundColor: 'silver',
        //    barBorderRadius: 7,
        //    barBorderWidth: 0,
        //    buttonBackgroundColor: 'silver',
        //    buttonBorderWidth: 0,
        //    buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
        //    buttonBorderRadius: 7,
        //    rilfeColor: 'yellow',
        //    trackBackgroundColor: 'none',
        //    trackBorderWidth: 1,
        //    trackBorderRadius: 8,
        //    trackBorderColor: '#CCC'
        //},

        title: {
            text: 'Voltage vs Date & Time',
            style: {
                //color: '#FF00FF',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            // categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true,
                showFull: false
            },
            alternateGridColor: '#FDFFD5',
            title: {
                text: 'Voltage (V)'
            }

        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                turboThreshold: 50000
            },
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    symbol: 'circle',
                    radius: 3
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Voltages Phase 1',
            color: 'red',
            data: arry_voltage_1,
        }, {
            name: 'Voltages Phase 2',
            color: 'yellow',
            data: arry_voltage_2,
        }, {
            name: 'Voltages Phase 3',
            color: 'blue',
            data: arry_voltage_3,
        },
        ],


    });
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or comment `showFull: false` in your `scrollbar: {enabled: true, showFull: false},` or set the value to true and it will work surely